# how can I use single call form action in twig

Tags: symfony

In Controller:

```
$entity = new Goods();
$form = $this->createForm(new GoodsType(), $entity, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('shop_goods_create'),
    'method' => 'POST',
));

$form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));
return $this->render('ShopAdminBundle:Goods:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

In View:
   I want get Action url.    it's like form form(form.action),i know this is wrong,hope that who can tell me a right method

Answer (score 0):

You can return form action url in your Controller action, like:

```
return $this->render('ShopAdminBundle:Goods:new.html.twig', array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
    'actionUrl' => $this->generateUrl('shop_goods_create');
));
```

Then in twig you can get your form action using `{{ actionUrl }}`

How to generate urls: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls

Comment: Well, I just want to know whether $this->createForm() template on the call form (form.action) method is similar.  But Thx~